# Accessing an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I'm trying to build a Rails app where I have to access the [Zomato API](http://www.zomato.com/api/documentation.)

Could anybody guide me on how to create the Controller and View. Suppose I want to get the name of the restaurant from this URL: [Restaurant](https://api.zomato.com/v1/restaurant.json/773), how do I write the controller and views for it. Currently, I'm using HTTParty gem.

This is my controller code:

```
def restaurants    
  @response = HTTParty.get("https://api.zomato.com/v1/restaurant.json/773", :headers => {"X-Zomato-API-Key" => "MYAPIKEY"})     
  puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect       
  @categories = Category.where(:category_name => 'Restaurants')      
end
```

And I'm trying to get the response object in the view:

```
<%= @response.each do |item| %>
  <td><%= item.id %></td>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.url %></td>
<% end %>
```

So, this shows the following error:

```
undefined method 'id' for ["id", 773]:Array
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a REST API, so you can write up a few ActiveResource classes and use it much like active record. Try reading up on the ActiveResource documentation.